# Application crashes while uploading image using retrofit on KitKat 4.4.4 API 19

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

As per the requirement, The user of the app clicks an image from device camera and then uploads it to server. Everything is working fine when I test my APK on Lollipop and above but when I test it on below Lollipop(specifically on KitKat 4.4.4 API 19) the app crashes with the exception `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)`.

Before passing the `intent` to `Camera` I am creating a `File` and passing it the `Uri`.Also during `File` creation I am saving the file path in some variable.

Later on `onActivityResult()`, I create a new file with the path(saved in variable) and then pass it to server using retrofit multipart.

This is how I pass `Intent` to `Camera`

```
Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE).also { takePictureIntent ->
                        takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(packageManager)?.also {
                            val photoFile = try {
                                createImageFile()
                            } catch (e: Exception) {
                                null
                            }

                            Log.e("file tag", photoFile!!.absolutePath)

                            photoFile?.also {
                                val photoUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this@PrintActivity, "$packageName.fileprovider", it)
                                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoUri)
                                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                                    takePictureIntent.clipData = ClipData.newRawUri("", photoUri)
                                    takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION)
                                }
                                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA)
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

The `createImageFile()` method is as follows :

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun createImageFile(): File {
        val timeStamp = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(Date())
        val storageDir = getExternalFilesDir("Allocation")
        return File.createTempFile("JPEG_${timeStamp}_", ".jpg", storageDir).apply {
            printImageFilePath = absolutePath
        }
    }
```

This is the `file_paths` I provided

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/$packageName/files/Allocation" />
</paths>
```

This is how I declared `Provider` in my `AndroidManifest` under the `application` tag

```
<provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="$packageName.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

This is the method `OnActivityResult()`

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            try {
                val printedImageFile = File(printImageFilePath)
                doImageUpload(printedImageFile)
            } catch (e: Throwable) {
                e.stackTrace
            }
        }
}
```

This is my `doImageUpload()` method

```
private fun doImageUpload(printedImageFile: File?) {
        if (networkUtil.isConnected()) {
            try {
                launch(UI) {
                    val response = dataManager.uploadImage(printedImageFile)
                    Log.v("ImageUploadSuccess", response.body())

}catch(e:Exception){

}

    }
```

This is my `dataManager.uploadImage(printedImageFile)` method

```
suspend fun uploadImage(printImageFile: File?): Response<String> {

        val printImageBody: RequestBody
        val printImagePart: MultipartBody.Part

            printImageBody = 
 RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/formdata"),printImageFile)
            printImagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("my_file1", printImageFile.name, printImageBody)
            restService.uploadImage(printImagePart).await()
}
```

And Finally this is my retrofit multipart interface method,

```
@Multipart
    @POST
    fun uploadImage(@Part myFile2: MultipartBody.Part?): Deferred<Response<String>>
```

This is the crash log I am receiving

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: $packageName, PID: 24339
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
    at okio.Okio.source(Okio.java:168)
    at okhttp3.RequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.java:119)
    at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.java:173)
    at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.java:114)
    at com.readystatesoftware.chuck.ChuckInterceptor.intercept(ChuckInterceptor.java:154)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
 Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EISDIR (Is a directory)
    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:398)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78) 
    at okio.Okio.source(Okio.java:168) 
    at okhttp3.RequestBody$3.writeTo(RequestBody.java:119) 
    at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeOrCountBytes(MultipartBody.java:173) 
    at okhttp3.MultipartBody.writeTo(MultipartBody.java:114) 
    at com.readystatesoftware.chuck.ChuckInterceptor.intercept(ChuckInterceptor.java:154) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) 
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254) 
    at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200) 
    at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error and with some help of my senior and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40128740/random-crash-on-capturing-image-on-lower-android-versions), I finally resolved the respective issue.

The issue was, as soon as I used to capture photo from back camera the android system was killing my respective `Activity` class in order to conserve resources. When the camera was closed and returned to my `Activity`, the  `Activity` was being re-created due to which the instance variable which was used to save the file path of the captured image was null. As a result the application used to crash.

So in order to preserve the instance variable I used `onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?)` method as follows, in my `PrintActivity` class(the `Activity` from which the `Camera Intent` was fired),

```
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle?) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    outState?.putString(Constants.PRINT_IMAGE_FILE_PATH,printImageFilePath) 
  // printImageFilePath is the path of the image file , 
 //  Constants.PRINT_IMAGE_FILE_PATH is my key for the bundle

}
```

And then in my `PrintActivity` inside the `onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`  I re-assign instance variable like this,

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    if(savedInstanceState?.get(Constants.PRINT_IMAGE_FILE_PATH)!=null){
    printImageFilePath = 
    savedInstanceState.get(Constants.PRINT_IMAGE_FILE_PATH)
  }
}
```